# Seeking detailed topographical map of Istanbul?

Tags: data, 3d, topography, turkey

I need to acquire a very detailed topographic map of *Istanbul, Turkey* without any markers. Do you know such sources who provides these kind of maps?  I tried to Google it, but the results were far from satisfactory. I found world topography from NASA, some low resolution images that does not worth much. There are a lot for US but unfortunately I failed to find one for Istanbul.

---

Actually since I don't the details of GIS, I don't know the technical terms to explain what I am looking for. But here is what I'll use the map for: I am going to print 3D version of Istanbul using some 3D printer, and display visualizations on top of it using projector hooked on the ceiling. In this case, I assume that I need either a 3D point cloud, or a 2D height map where I can deduce 3D points after some processing.

Comment: Thanks for welcome. I edited my question, if you need to have more information please do tell me.

Comment: Topographic Map Hike&Bike http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Istanbul/

Comment: If this may be open data then the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be the best place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're after is a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_elevation_model)) which represents surface elevation as a single band raster (i.e. your 2D height map).

One starting point for getting DEM data is the [USGS EarthExplorer data portal (http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) which allows you to select a region and search for data. If you use the map to zoom to Istanbul and the area you're interested in click the `Use Map` button to select your entire map view for data. In the `Data Sets` tab expand out `Digital Elevation` and select `ASTER GLOBAL DEM` which is 30m resolution DEM data. You may have to stick some scenes together as I believe the tiles neatly bisect Istanbul, but it will hopefully be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. One last question, please forgive my ignorance about the subject. Once I downloaded the tif files, even though I can see DEM on website with low resolution, I cannot see anything on default photo viewer software (Picasa Image Viewer). Should I do any additional step?

Comment: @MertToka No worries. Welcome to the field! I'd advise using [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) to view the data - it's a single band tif file, and the values don't scale nicely for viewing in photo viewers (think of it as a 2d array of data). To get started take a look at the documentation on [Loading Raster Data in QGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/supported_data.html#load-raster)